# Qt Project qmake Error on Building

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmake, qtcore

I'm new at Qt. I made a Qt Quick Application. When I try to build project, compiler gives this error:

```
23:26:42: Running steps for project Basla...
23:26:42: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\5.2.0\msvc2012_64_opengl\bin\qmake.exe" C:\Users\TaeZ-Stkyoht\Documents\Ders\Qt\Başla\Basla\Basla.pro -r -spec win32-msvc2012 "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=declarative_debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
Cannot find file: C:\Users\TaeZ-Stkyoht\Documents\Ders\Qt\Başla\Basla\Basla.pro.
23:26:42: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\5.2.0\msvc2012_64_opengl\bin\qmake.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Basla (kit: Desktop Qt 5.2.0 MSVC2012 OpenGL 64bit)
When executing step 'qmake'
23:26:42: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

Comment: Can you show your project file? Does that exist? ""C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\5.2.0\msvc2012_64_opengl\bin\qmake.exe" C:\Users\TaeZ-Stkyoht\Documents\Ders\Qt\Başla\Basla\Basla.pro"? Have you tried to change the "Başla" to "Basla" in that path to see if the error goes away, i.e. utf8 to ascii?

Comment: ş to s solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a known and unresolved issue in general:

[qmake should interpret project file encoding as utf-8](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-27896)

As you can realize in your output, the problem takes place when invoking the `qmake` executable on the desired project file. Your path seems to be constructed as utf rather than ascii based on this folder entry:

```
"Başla"
```

This is an issue for qmake since it uses `QFile`, `QDir`, et al underneath. As you can read that in the bugreport, those are handled as latin 1, not utf. This may be an issue in your scenario.

The workaround would be probably to change the `Başla` entry to `Basla` just like it happens to be for the rest of the path. That would at least make it probably working, and bring also some consistency into your path.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, qmake is rather clever and always trying to tell you what is going wrong, here the problem is in missing file:

```
 Cannot find file: C:\Users\TaeZ-Stkyoht\Documents\Ders\Qt\Başla\Basla\Basla.pro
```

It seems to me that it couldn't find this file because of that strange letter:
..\Ba**ş**la\Basla\Basla.pro

I would recommend you to place all your projects to C:\Projects\ to avoid such problems. Hope it will help.

Comment: "I would recommend you to place all your projects to C:\Projects\ to avoid such problems." -> That is not relevant.